# function return style logical and is okay?

Tags: c++, return

`func()` invokes 3 different functions `f1()`, `f2()`, `f3()`.

my function return BOOL, logical AND for 3 functions,

is this okay(normal)?

```
BOOL func(...)
{
  //...
  return ( f1() && f2() && f3());
}
```

Comment: Style is highly subjective and asking about it will lead to this question being closed. As for the logic, remember that the boolean operators `&&` and `||` uses [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). So in your case if the first function returns `false` then the rest of the function will not be called. And can you please elaborate on what problems you have with the code you show? Why are you posting this question? Are you only asking us to *review* your code? Is there some other problem with it? Something you don't understand?

Comment: i want to verify my code, to prevent bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that builtin [`operator &&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) perform short-circuit evaluation; i.e. if `f1()` returns `false` then `f2()` and `f3()` won't be invoked.

If this is fine for your intent, then the code looks fine.

Comment: that's fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly fine and valid syntax regardless of the what f1, f2, and f3 return. But that if any one of those functions output something that could translate to false the entire expression will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

```
return ( f1() && f2() && f3());
```

If the return value of the call to `f1()` is false `f2()` and `f3()` never gets called.

Comment: that's okay. f1() must return true. then have to run f2(), so on.